# How is html in email is different from web pages

Tags: html, css, email

I want to start creating html templates..But I have no idea how to do it. If i just copy paste  my html/css then it shows up but somethings are broken. More things break down for recipient. ...and i have no idea why.

It's clear jquery won't work! Why some html and css things aren't working either? Am i stuck using tables for this?

If you open up html file like in chrome, press ctrl+a > ctrl+c then go to gmail and press ctrl+v then all html along css gets copied, this is how did it and maybe it's what is causing me trouble, but again somethings don't..For example vertical and horizontal centering using table of outermost div isn't working it expands to fill.

I'd like some tutorial to explain the things or if guidelines are simple and easy then please let me know here.

Comment: [basics](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+email+tutorial) and [state of the art](http://alistapart.com/article/can-email-be-responsive)

Comment: why down vote this is legit question that many people would benefit from knowing.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/

Comment: This isn't a very good fit for the StackOverflow site. If you are having specific issues with formatting HTML for emails then by all means ask those. A blanket question like this is too broad and would solicit a lot of off topic discussion.

Answer (score 2):

You have to bear in mind that Email clients are not always as up to date in CSS compliance terms as their browser relatives. Also you have no idea what mail client the user is likely to see your email in, whether it is Outlook, Mozilla Thunderbird or whatever. Some email clients will only support basic CSS. With email clients, it is also more likely that people will be using older versions of the software e.g Outlook 2007/10 instead of 2013.

There are no hard and fast rules except to state that the simpler you keep the HTML, the more likely it is that the email client will show it as you intended.

As for using tables, you are stuck with using them if you want your email to be formatted properly on as many email clients as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Different mail clients have very different CSS support.
A good comprehensive guide can be found [**on Campaign Monitor**](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) both on-site and with links to download.

A small excerpt:

[image: Sample image]

They also feature a solid templating engine on-site.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main reasons:

The email programs do not share the same web engine as the standard browsers thus won't render them correctly.

Even if you open email in a web browser which uses standard web engines, the content containing html tags are often altered to prevent potential hacks.

Comment: And since mobile is used heavily for email..much advantage of tables is gone as well?